# WebSphere liberty - shared libraries on docker image

Tags: docker, maven, websphere-liberty

I am using websphere-liberty(https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty/) image to deploy my apps but I have problems with shared libraries. I need to transform  jar from util project into shared libraries on liberty server. Im stuck on this error:

SchedulerApplication- loaded ok - is from Scheduler app but it is extending class from util project

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [Scheduler]: 

    javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [Scheduler]: com.scheduler.SchedulerApplication was found, but is missing another required class.
    SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.
    SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path
    SRVE0234I: Application class path=[com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader@3c27eabb]
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1575)
            at [internal classes]
```

---

```
Basic project structure
    app - Scheduler/...
                /pom.xml
        - myapp2/...
                /pom.xml
        - util/...
              /pom.xml
        - pom.xml
    Dockerfile
    server.xml
```

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-ibmjava-8 as maven_build
COPY --chown=1001:0 app./app
WORKDIR app
RUN mvn clean install

FROM websphere-liberty:21.0.0.12-full-java8-ibmjava
COPY --chown=1001:0  server.xml /config/
COPY --chown=1001:0 --from=maven_build /app/Scheduler/target/Scheduler.ear /config/dropins/ 
COPY --chown=1001:0 --from=maven_build /app/myapp2/target/myapp2.ear /config/dropins/

#util -> libraries used in both Scheduler & myapp2
COPY --chown=1001:0 --from=maven_build /app/util/target/util.jar /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/lib/
RUN configure.sh
```

---

server.xml

```
.....
<library id="SharedLibraries" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, stable, third-party">
    <fileset dir="/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/lib/" includes="*.jar" scanInterval="5s" />
</library>

<application id="Scheduler" name="Scheduler" type="ear" location="Scheduler.ear">
      <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, stable, third-party" commonLibraryRef="SharedLibraries" />   
</application>
.....
```

Comment: Fixed after moving ear file out of config/dropins  => stopped auto deploying
e.g.
COPY --chown=1001:0 --from=maven_build /app/Scheduler/target/Scheduler.ear /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps

Comment: If you fixed the problem it's perfectly OK to write it up as an answer to your own question (and it's more obvious that the question was answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after moving ear file out of config/dropins => stopped auto deploying

Looks like app was installed 2x
-auto deploy from config/dropins & deploy from server.xml

```
COPY --chown=1001:0 --from=maven_build /app/Scheduler/target/Scheduler.ear /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps
```